# Why do application notes/report become obsolete? Am i using a superseded method? Phase locked loops

Tags: charge-pump, phase

**Preface**
I need to use a phase locked loop to lock onto a signal that can vary from 30Hz to 65 Hz and want to implement it digitally. After some general research I found that Zero crossing phase locked loops were relatively easy to implement in software. So i decided to use this type of PLL.

**Question**
I was trying to work out how to implement my loop filter and came across these notes on component selection http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snaa015b/snaa015b.pdf. Though these say obsolete at the top, does this mean that the charge pump pll has been superseded by another type of pll?

**Me asking you to do my work for me** If you know, could you recommend to me what type of PLL i should be using?

Comment: What caused that report to be marked obsolete is that the the chip [LMX2315](http://www.ti.com/product/lmx2315) has been marked as obsolete by TI.

Comment: Guess that's a lack of research on my part, sorry. I should have known that hardware becomes obsolete not design techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest cause of parts becoming "obsolete" was the move to lead free requirements under the ROHS directive. In those cases there is usually a direct replacement, but with a modified part number.